# Imagehosting image thumbnails disappear after refreshing the page in Forums

Tags: javascript, jquery, phpbb, phpbb3, mybb

I'm creating forum on my site and I'm facing an issue while posting bb image code links.
This was also the issue when I installed phpbb forum.

When I create a new thread consisting of images from other image-hosting sites, the thumbnails of images are showing on the forum only for the first time. As soon as I refresh the page, the thumbnails are replaced with broken image icon. But the page still redirects to the correct image-hosting page.

**This is how it looks after refreshing the page:**
[image: This is how it looks after refreshing the page]

**This is what I get after Inspect element.**
[image: This is what I get after Inspect element.]

In the above image the first anchor tag is working but in the second anchor tag it added "pagespeed.ic.vCpxnjVn6L.webp".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
Added the following code in .htaccess file in root directory.

`ModPagespeed off
    ModPagespeedDisallow http://sitename/*`